# Slide Out Menu without a back Button

Tags: objective-c, xcode, tabslideout

I use `SWRevealViewController` for my Slide Out Menu. I did actually the same like he did it here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5SUV1YY2yxQ, but even I add a new ViewController and connect it with the segue "reveal view controller", start the app and click on the row to open the view controller, it will works, but I don't have a back Button. Why?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to make your initial view controller a navigation controller via the Menu bar > edit > embedded > navigation controller. That should make it so your transitions carry the back button hopefully. If that doesn't work maybe you can programmatically make a button or drag one yourself and wire that together.