# Back Button not present in SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uinavigationcontroller, swrevealviewcontroller

How to add back button to the original View controller in SWRevealViewController?

I've checked these and Tried them both didn't works: 
[Slide Out Menu without a back Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31100570/slide-out-menu-without-a-back-button)
[Swift Custom Back Button and Destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24844568/swift-custom-back-button-and-destination)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok sorry my bad, of corse this old answer wouldn't work, I even did used this SWRevealViewContoller in a old project.

1.) Add navigation controller to view controller you want to show.
2.) Add Back Button on view controller
3.) Control-click drag from table view to new Navagation Controller.
4.) Choose Present Modally
5.) Control Click-drag from the back button to the Main View Controller (one you changed its class to "SWRevealViewController")
6.) Choose Present Modally

**This is a more In-depth Explanation.**
(1)So from your on your view you want to link to the slide out menu you want to add a navigation controller to it. (2)Then you can change the text of the nav bar and add a button to the nav. bar. (3)Now you want to go to your table view controller (slide out menu) and control click and drag to the navigation controller that is linked to the view controller you want to display. (4)You want to choose the present modally option from the menu that appears. (5)Then you are going to control click and drag to the Main View controller (the one you set its class to "SWRevealViewController"). (6)You want to again choose the Present Modally Option.

Comment: can't do it in SWRevealViewController only Reveal Controller push controller

Comment: Is the "Collections" table view controller the one you are trying to display? And is that cancel button the back button you are talking about?

Comment: yes indeed , no the cancel button will dismiss the  VC

Comment: your way did actually put it pops out and menu pulled to the middle after pressing cancel

Comment: So is everything working to you liking, Do you understand all of it now?

Comment: Ok great! Glad I could help! :)